# Extracting all class names from a solution in vs 2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to extract all class names from my solution in C3 vs 2008. I am able to do this for a single project using reflection passing the assembly name. But the problem is how can i get this working for my entire solution?.

Is there any way i can extract all assembly names from my solution? My solution basically has 10 projects and i want to extract information from all projects.

Comment: Any reason why this was downvoted? Seems like a perfectly reasonable, clear question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not about a run time, you can try to use ILDasm tool to fetch class names from a compiled assembly. For example:

```
ildasm /text /classlist /noil <file_name>
```

or a next command to parse all libraries in a current folder:

```
for %f in (*.dll) do ildasm /text /classlist /noil %f
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution file will list all the projects in the solution - it is a fairly straight forward text file to parse. You can use this to get a list of all the projects and then use your current approach.